# Weird error TypeError: Cannot read property 'getValue' of null

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamics-crm, dom-events

I get this weird error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getValue' of null

when I want to get the value of another field depend on the change of unit Field and be informed that the 2 fields (project and Unit) are lookup fields. This is my code:

```
function OnChanegUnit() 
  {
    debugger;
    var UnitId = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ph_phdunitId").getValue();
     if (UnitId != null) 
    {
        var oDataSetName = "ph_phdunitSet";
        var columns = "ph_projectnameid";
        var filter = "ph_phdunitId eq (guid'" + UnitId[0].id + "') ";
        var results = retrieveMultiple(oDataSetName, columns, filter);
        if (results != "")
        { 
            if (results[0].ph_projectnameid.Id != null) 
            {

                SetLookup("ph_project", results[0].ph_projectnameid.Id, results[0].ph_projectnameid.Name, results[0].ph_projectnameid.LogicalName);
            }
            else {
                Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ph_project").setValue(null);
                Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ph_project").setSubmitMode("always");
            }
             }
    }
    else{
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ph_project").setValue(null);
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ph_project").setSubmitMode("always");
       }
}
```

Comment: You haven't provided any code?

Comment: Please provide a [example]

Comment: @tony-medhat It's not a weird error, to be frank, it's the most obvious and frequent error in JavaScript world.

Comment: Here the error is telling you that your `object` is `null`. Hence, you can't access it's property `getValue`. Because as you see, logically a `null` **(something that is nothing)**, can not have any properties associated to it. Apart from this, it'd be helpful if you edit your question, and share your code too here.

Comment: @Kobe kindly check code now

Comment: @AadityaSharma I edit my post with my code and wait your support

Comment: Let's look at `var UnitId = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ph_phdunitId").getValue();`. Here `Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ph_phdunitId")` evaluates to `null`. Seems, whatever `Xrm.page` does, it is unable to find the attribute `"ph_phdunitId"` in your page.

Comment: after change (Ph_PhdunitId) with right one ( ph_unitId) it could to pass this step and but appear another error cannot recognize it <CrmScriptErrorReport>
  <ReportVersion>1.0</ReportVersion>
  <ScriptErrorDetails>
   <Message>Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined</Message>
   <Line>15</Line>

Comment: results[0] here is your 2nd error. Reason your results does not return an array.  You have debugger in your code, why not debug steps by step and see where you face issue. Right now your retreivemultiple does not return results.

Comment: `Xrm.Page` is deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code is related to this line:

`var UnitId = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ph_phdunitId").getValue();`

with Xrm functions, the field names must always be lowercase, so the correct code is

`var UnitId = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ph_phdunitid").getValue();`

of course this will work if the field is in the form

regarding the other error

`Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

it can be related to `results` coming from your custom function

Comment: after check my custom function now is working fine thanks all for your support

Comment: @TonyMedhat this is where you mark this answer as being the answer.